# how to convert flash based interactive animations for iPad

Tags: javascript, ios, html, ipad, flash

I am trying to develop a mobile app(iPad) for a client who has an e-learning website. The website consists of quite a few simple flash based interactive animations. I would like to know which would be the best way to proceed??A native app or a html5 based app. If so how do I covert the flash based interactive animation for the ipad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Adobe Edge for developing HTML5, CSS3 based animation which works very well in ipads.

Comment: Can I create interactive (user inputs/actions) flash contents using Edge. Can I convert the flash based content using tools such as Wallaby or Swiffy.

Comment: Yes you can create interactive contents using edge. But I don't think that it will convert the flash based content directly to JS,HTML,CSS animation. And no idea about Wallaby or Swiffy.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the exakt animations and have flash cs you van download the createJS plugin which allows
conversion of timeline animation to Javascript code. Doesnt work if its AS3 coded though I think.